# Reading and writing access database table in python

Tags: python, sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have an access database. Inside are a few tables I created. I want to use python to read through one of the tables and make a list of everything in a column. I want to compare that list to another list already created in my program, and output  a "YES" in the same row new column of the access spreadsheet I made, if that number matches one in the list. SSimilarly, I want to output "NO" on the database table if that number doesn't match one in the list.

I have already made my list from another excel sheet. I now need to read in the files from an excel sheet. I cannot use the module "MySQLdb" for it doesn't allow me to download on my computer.

SO my question is:

How can I read and write in a table in excel? I have tried everything all day including MySQL and other stack overflow questions. None of them match what I am writing right now. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The title is (currently) "Reading and writing **access database** table in python", but after a vague description of what you want to accomplish you ask "How can I read and write in a table in **excel**?". Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to better describe what you are *really* asking about.

Comment: Please clarify: 1) Is your data stored in an Access **database** or an Excel **spreadsheet**? 2) Where do you want the data to be output -- to an Access **database**, or an Excel **spreadsheet**?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the table to csv so you can open it with excel

Try this:

```
    import csv

roomnumber = 0.00
roomname = 0.00
lueftungList = []

import time

class Lueftung:

    def getData(self):
        global roomnumber
        global roomname


        roomnumber = input("roomnumber: ")
        roomname = input("roomname  : ")



    myFormattedList = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in lueftungList ]



    def main(self):
        global roomnumber
        global roomname



    lueftungList.append(["", roomnumber, roomname, "", ""])


    lueftungList.insert(0,[(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")), "roomnumber", "roomname",])


    # convert to csv
    with open("lueftung.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
        for row in lueftungList:
            cwriter.writerow(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    luft = Lueftung()
    luft.main()
```